# How do I destroy a view that is added by pushViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

After adding a view by `pushViewController` method, there will be a back button in the navigation bar to pop the view off the stack. However, it seems that iOS won't destroy the view after popping it off the stack so when will it be destroyed? Can we destroy it manually when popping out the view?

Answer (score 2):

Generally the pattern is like this:

```
- (void)pushSomeViewControllerOnStack
{
    SomeViewController* someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
    [someViewController release];
}
```

In other words, the navigation controller will do its own `retain` of the view controller, which means you *also* need to `release` it yourself, since there's an `init`. The navigation controller will also take care of releasing this controller when appropriate.

Comment: thanks Shaggy Frog, but my problem is the view now only release by the system autorelease mechanism, can I release it manually when popping out the view?

Comment: First view controllers are what gets popped off the stack, not views. Second, view controllers take care to release their associated view; you shouldn't be worrying about releasing views the way you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc` methods within your `UIViewController` subclasses.

When a `UINavigationController` pops a view controller off its stack the code within those methods will be executed.

You should read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS: Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) documentation from Apple's iOS Developer Library as well as the class reference documentation for the [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController) and [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) classes so that you will better understand the view controller life cycle and what to expect when various application events occur.